# Find the solution of $X''+u^2X=0$ with boundary conditions $X(0)=0$, $~X(1)+X'(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From $X''+u^2X=0$ we find
$$
X=c \cos{ux} + d\sin{ux}
$$
and from the boundary condition we have 
$$
c=0,\quad
d(\sin u + u\cos u)=0
$$
Since we want nontrivial solutions we must have ($d \neq 0$)
$$
\sin u+ u\cos u =0
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\tan u=-u
$$

Comment: Try writing your solution to the  equation as $X(x;u)=Ae^{i u x}+Be^{-i u x}$ where $i$ is the complex unit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are done now! This is an eigen-value problem which has infinitely many solutions for different values of $u_n,\,\,n=1,2,...,\infty$. You should note that the **characteristic** equation $\tan(u)=-u$ has infinitely real roots. Also, it is easy to verify that if $u$ is solution then $-u$ is a solution and hence you need to just find the positive roots. Also, as the negative roots won't give you any linearly independent eigen-functions compared to those given by positive roots, so you can simply neglect the negative roots. Hence, the final solution will be

$$\begin{array}{}
X_n(x)=\sin(u_nx) & n=1,2,... \\
\tan(u_n)=u_n & u_n \gt 0
\end{array}$$